# Anyone knows the purpose of the manifest.mf file?

Tags: servlets

Inside meta-inf folder, there is a manifest.mf. Anyone knows what's the purpose of this file?

Comment: [jcabi-manifests](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-manifests/index.html) provides a useful utility class to work with that MANIFEST.MF files, take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MANIFEST.MF file is explained in detail [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html).

Here is the summary:

> JAR files can support a wide range of functionality, including electronic signing, version control, package sealing, extensions, and others. What gives JAR files the ability to be so versatile? The answer is embodied in the JAR file's manifest.
>
> The manifest is a special file that can contain information about the files packaged in a JAR file. By tailoring this "meta" information that the manifest contains, you enable the JAR file to be used for a variety of purposes.